# play.google.com and Google Play app out of sync

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, restore, htc-one-x

Having become fed up with a custom ROM i was using, I reverted back to a previous ROM via a nandroid backup (through CWM Touch).
It would appear that the backup preserved all my installed apps and data (Was under the impression they didn't, so this surprised me somewhat), but since then the 'My Apps' listing on the google play website has been out of sync with what is actually on my phone. I also seem unable to request (un)installation through the web interface.

Help would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check that your Google Account is still linked in Settings > Accounts and Sync?

Comment: Yep, i I tried removing the account,  then adding it back through the play store, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the link to the Play store was lost. I think if you install an app from, say, the amazon app store, Google Play will not be able to update or uninstall it, as the link is gone. Similarly, restoring an app from a previous rom backup may not create that link.

[Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) can recreate the links (the free version <strike>can</strike> can't do this). Or you could uninstall the app and try installing it fresh from Google Play.

Comment: Where would I find the option? All the references to relinking apps on the android market/google play that i've managed to find required the donate/pro edition.

(I'm probably looking in the wrong place)

Comment: Not to worry. Ended up buying a TiBu PRO key anyway. Market Doctor fixe it up perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you're right. The re-linking requires the Pro version. I was looking in the summary of the app and it implies it is in the free version as well. Glad you got your problem fixed!